# How to determine if a variable is returning a comparable statement

Tags: powershell

```
if ((Get-ChildItem "I:\temp").Length -ne 0) {
    $locations = (Get-Item "I:\temp"), (Get-ChildItem "I:\temp" -Directory -Recurse) | % {
        Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName |
            Select-String -List -Pattern '^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$' | 
            % Path
    }

    if ($locations) {
        $locations | Out-File "I:\temp\SSN_FILES.txt"
    } else {
        Get-ChildItem "I:\temp" -Exclude "fullpath.txt", "SSN_FILES.txt" | Remove-Item
    }
}
```

I need to determine if `$locations` is true or not. If it is true it performs the first operation, if false it performs the second operation. The problem that I am running into is that I can't find a way to determine of `$locations` is true (equal to a matching regex) or not.

Comment: `if ($locations) ...` tests to see if it's `$null` or zero, or an equivalent. You should probably take a look at the `-match` operator (see [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)).

Comment: [Related](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced this problem before where the `if` returns `true` if the variable exists, and is set to a non-false value (not necessarily to true, but some value).

Do this:

```
if($locations -eq $true){ # to check it is set to the boolean true
if($locations -ne $null){ # to check if it contains a value
```

Comment: I had that before and I don't believe that works. Reason being I don't think $locations is returning a boolean statement. I had this before and I don't believe it was working the way I had intended.

Comment: the output into the file is `True`. `$locations` should have the path to the file that equals the regex.

Comment: perhaps the test you're after is `$locations -ne $null`? As if it contains values, should be not null. If no values returned by the regex, should be null.

Comment: this works. I was thinking of doing it this way, but didn't think it would work... hehehe

Comment: @schnipdip sweet - edited into ans. This is still a pain point for me; watch out for errors/unexpected output getting captured into the `$locations` variable and the `-ne $null` test returning true

Comment: well it was working, now something got messed up because it doesn't delete the files once it checks them.